# Kendo Grid custom command button click event does not fire

Tags: backbone.js, kendo-ui

i have loaded some data using backbone collection and kendo grid. I have added a custom update command and assigned a event but the even does not fire. Please Help.

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({



             editable: true,
             batch: true,

          columns: ["Name", "Description", "Date", { command: { text: "Update Me",    name:"Update", click: onEdit }, title: " ", width: "140px"}],
            dataSource: {

                schema: {
                    model: docWrapper


                    },
                 data: new documentlistWrapper((window.docs))

              },


            pageSize:5

        });

    }
    });

function onEdit(e)
{

    alert("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your braces (`{}`) are not correctly balanced. Try this instead:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    editable  : true,
    batch     : true,
    columns   : ["Name", "Description", "Date", { command: { text: "Update Me", name: "Update", click: onEdit }, title: " ", width: "140px"}],
    dataSource: {
        schema: {
            model: docWrapper
        },
        data  : new documentlistWrapper((window.docs))
    },
    pageSize  : 5
});

function onEdit(e) {
    alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: sorry i have put some extra bracket mistakenly...... brackets are not an issue here ....... can you suggest something else?

Comment: Check it [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/UvJ4g/) working. Please, check what do you have different.